# How do I fix this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error?

Tags: c#, object-reference

I am getting a `System.NullReferenceException` error when I run this program.
It is saying that

> the object reference is not set to an instance of an object

But I pretty sure that that's exactly what I am doing in line 11. Any ideas on how to fix this are very much appreciated.

[image: Obejct Reference not set to an instance of an object]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: one of the possible answers is that the array is not initialized but I'm pretty sure I did that in line 11. In every example I look at online, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csa` is an array of instances of a user-defined class called `CurryStudent`. On line number 11 you instantiated the array of `CurryStudent` class. Here you forgot to fill an array with its elements that are nothing but an instance of `CurryStudent` class.

You need to instanciate each element of `csa` array with an instance of class `CurryStudent`.
Like,

```
for(int i = 0; i < csa.Length; i++)
    csa[i] = new CurryStudent();
```

Answer (score 1):

At line 11 you init an array with length 2 but is is still empty to fill it add

```
csa[0] = new CurryStudent();
csa[1] = new CurryStudent();
```

Comment: @AlexAntoine if this is the correct answers, please upvote and mark is as correct to help other who find this post

Comment: I can't I have less than 15 reputation. It won't be publicly displayed

Answer (score 1):

You create a list of CarryStudent[] csa.
Then you ask for the first element in that list.
But your first element in that list is nothing yet, you did not populate your list with elements of type CarryStudent. Thus the exception